# How to arrange an array vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I am trying to arrange a 2d array vertically and horizontally, while incrementing it by a given value. I was able to figure out how to do it horizontally with this method:

```
  public static void fillRight (int [][] fillRightArray, int step){

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< fillRightArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< fillRightArray[i].length; j++){
            count++;
            fillRightArray[i][j] += step*count;
          //  fillRightArray[i][j] += step*(i+1);


            System.out.print(fillRightArray[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

So the horizontal arrangement looks like this when i print:

```
2 4 6 8 10
12 14 16 18
20 22 24 26
```

Now for the vertical version, I tried multiple attempts and nothing seems to work. I know it is very similar to the fillRightArray but I cant seem to figure it out.

The closest ive gotten is:

```
public static void fillDown(int [][] fillDownArray, int step){

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<fillDownArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< fillDownArray[i].length; j++){
            count++;
            fillDownArray[i][j] += step*(i+1);

            System.out.print(fillDownArray[i][j]+ " ");
       }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Where the output comes out to be:

```
 2 2 2 2 2
 4 4 4 4 4
 6 6 6 6 6
 8 8 8 8 8
 10 10 10 10 10
```

Any idea on how I can make it look like:

```
2 12 22 32
4 14 24 34
6 16 26 36
8 18 28 38
10 20 30 40
```

Comment: For accessing elements in a vertical manner. you can reverse the looping variables (i,j) to (j,i). If this was not the solution you were looking for, let me know I can try to explain better.

Comment: @hybrid so for the print i should do fillDownArray[j][i]? Because when i tried that it change the array. Instead of being say a 5x8, it turned it into a 8x5 for some reason. Could you explain it a bit more? Many thanks

Comment: Basically, when you try to do it vertically, you are taking the transpose of the 2D matrix which will revert the row count with column count.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply **transpose** the array in-place see below how

```
// transpose in-place
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        int temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[j][i];
        a[j][i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void fillRight (int [][] fillRightArray, int step){

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< fillRightArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< fillRightArray[i].length; j++){
            count++;
            fillRightArray[i][j] += step*count;
            System.out.print(fillRightArray[j][i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the second dimension of the array is always the same size, you can separate out the calculation and printing:

```
public static void fillDown(int[][] fillDownArray, int step) {
    //Calculate the values
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fillDownArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fillDownArray[i].length; j++) {
            count++;
            fillDownArray[i][j] += step * count;
        }
    }

    //Print array
    for (int j = 0; j < fillDownArray[0].length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fillDownArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(fillDownArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I agree with the answer on transposing as a tidy solution to flipping a preexisting 2 dimensional array, I'm not convinced this answers the author's question, since the method he is making intends to populate and display the 2 dimensional array.

For the task of populating and printing to the console, let's consider what you need to achieve.

In order to print the 2 dimensional array as you wish we have to first print index `0` of all the nested arrays, so `fillDownArray[0][0]`, `fillDownArray[1][0]`, `fillDownArray[2][0]` etc.

So given we are also populating prior to printing, how can we figure out what the value should be?

Assuming `step = 2` and `fillDownArray` being initialized as `new int[5][5]`:

For `fillDownArray[0][0]` we want `2`: `step` `(= 2)`

For `fillDownArray[1][0]` we want `12`: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step`

For `fillDownArray[2][0]` we want `22`: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * 2`

For `fillDownArray[3][0]` we want `32`: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * 3`

For `fillDownArray[4][0]` we want `42`: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * 4`

---

There's a pattern here, and the first two can be re-worked to match the subsequent ones:

For `fillDownArray[0][0]` we want `2`: `step`, which is the same as: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * 0`

For `fillDownArray[1][0]` we want `12`:  `step + fillDownArray[0].length`, which is the same as: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * 1`

So, if we consider the indicies of the first dimension to be `i` and second dimension `j` (i.e. `fillDownArray[i][j]`), then we just need to replace the number at the end of the calculation with `i`, resulting in:

`fillDownArray[i][j] = step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * i;`

But this isn't complete for solving the problem. We must also think about the second dimension.

---

There's a similar pattern going through the second dimension:

I'll ignore for when `i = 0` and go straight into identifying the pattern.

For `fillDownArray[1][0]` we want `12`: `step + fillDownArray[0].length * step * i` (as before)

For `fillDownArray[1][1]` we want `14`: `step * 2 + fillDownArray[0].length * step * i`

For `fillDownArray[1][2]` we want `16`: `step * 3 + fillDownArray[0].length * step * i`

etc.

As you can hopefully see, the pattern of change here is at the start of the calculation: `step * n`, where `n` is a number starting at `1` and increasing by `1` each time we iterate over the second dimension.

So what is `n`? It's `j + 1`, where `j` in the variable used for the second dimension.

Now bringing this alltogether into an implementation, we now know we must first iterate over the first dimension (`i`), then the second (`j`), which means the iteration over the second dimension is the outer loop, and first dimension inner.

```
public static void fillDown(int[][] fillDownArray, int step) {
    final int NESTED_ARRAY_LENGTH = fillDownArray[0].length; // This approach assumes all nested arrays are the same length
    for (int j = 0; j < NESTED_ARRAY_LENGTH; j++) { // outer loop, iterates the second dimension
        for (int i = 0; i < fillDownArray.length; i++) { // inner loop, iterates the first dimension
            fillDownArray[i][j] = step * (j + 1) + NESTED_ARRAY_LENGTH * step * i;
            System.out.print(fillDownArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This implementation will work for all cases where the length of the second dimension is the same in all cases.